# Decode list of strings

Tags: elm

How does one decode a list of strings from JSON? I have this code that currently fails every time:

```
import Html exposing (..)
import Html.App as App
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)
import Html.Events exposing (onInput, onClick)
import Http
import Json.Decode as Json exposing ((:=))
import Json.Decode exposing (object3)
import Task



main =
  App.program
    { view = view
    , init = init
    , update = update
    , subscriptions = subscriptions
    }



init : (Model, Cmd Msg)
init =
  (Model "" { productName = "", brand = "", alternateImagePaths = [] }, Cmd.none)


-- MODEL

type alias Product =
  { productName : String
  , brand : String
  , alternateImagePaths : List String
  }

type alias Model =
  { id : String
  , product : Product}

-- UPDATE


type Msg
  = GetProduct
  | UpdateText String
  | FetchSucceed Product
  | FetchFail Http.Error


update : Msg -> Model -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
update msg model =
  case msg of
    GetProduct ->
      (model, getData model.id)

    UpdateText text ->
      ({ model | id = text }, Cmd.none )

    FetchSucceed p ->
      ({ model | product = p } , Cmd.none)

    FetchFail _ ->
      ({ model | id = "" }, Cmd.none)


-- VIEW


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  div []
    [ input [ type' "text", onInput UpdateText ] []
    , button [ type' "button", onClick GetProduct ] [ text "Search" ]
    , br [] []
    , pre [] [ text model.id ]
    , pre [] [ text (toString model.product) ]
    ]


-- HTTP


getData : String -> Cmd Msg
getData id =
  let
    url = "https://localhost:3000/v2/product/" ++ id
  in
    Task.perform FetchFail FetchSucceed (Http.get decodeData url)


decodeData : Json.Decoder Product
decodeData =
  object3 Product
    ("productName" := Json.string)
    ("brand" := Json.string)
    ("alternateImagePaths" := Json.list Json.string)


subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
  Sub.none
```

If I remove the `alternateImagePaths`, it hits the `FetchSucceed` function but if I leave it, it hits the `FetchFail` function.

Data structure (actual response):

```
{
  "productName": "Men's San Francisco 49ers Design Your Own T-Shirt-",
  "team": [
    "San Francisco 49ers"
  ],
  "brand": "Pro Line",
  "shippingTimeFrame": 3
}
```

**EDIT:** This apparently happens when you somehow get a property that does not exist anymore.

Comment: @ChadGilbert Do you need the entire JSON object?

Comment: Is that the actual json? Brand doesn't have a trailing comma while alternateImagePaths does and the keys aren't quoted

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have a valid JSON?  You should always validate it
before letting client code consume it.

Here is working code after a small fix.

```elm
import Html exposing (text)
import Json.Decode exposing (..)

json = """
{
  "productName": "Panthers Shirt",
  "brand": "Nike",
  "alternateImagePaths": ["url.com", "url2.com"],
  "dummy": "dummyval"
}
"""

main =
  text <| toString (decodeString decodeData json)

type alias Product =
  { productName : String
  , brand : String
  , alternateImagePaths : List String
  }

decodeData : Decoder Product
decodeData =
  object3 Product
    ("productName" := string)
    ("brand" := string)
    ("alternateImagePaths" := list string)
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, the problem is that `alternateImagePaths` may or may not be included in the json you want to decode. There are a few ways to handle this.

1. You could use `oneOf` to look for `alternateImagePaths` and succeed if it is anything *but* a string list. This is a quick 'n dirty way of handling it because you'd still get an empty list if `alternateImagePaths` was something else, like an integer:

```elm
decodeData : Json.Decoder Product
decodeData =
    Json.object3 Product
        ("productName" := Json.string)
        ("brand" := Json.string)
        (Json.oneOf ["alternateImagePaths" := Json.list Json.string, Json.succeed []])
```

2. You could also use the [NoRedInk/elm-decode-pipeline](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/NoRedInk/elm-decode-pipeline/latest/Json-Decode-Pipeline) package which handles this case explicitly with the `optional` decoder.

```elm
decodeData : Json.Decoder Product
decodeData =
    decode Product
        |> required "productName" Json.string
        |> required "brand" Json.string
        |> optional "alternateImagePaths" (Json.list Json.string) []
```

I'd recommend using the `elm-decode-pipeline` version. In my opinion, it makes things a little easier to read and it handles these edge cases missed by the core package.